# PayPal IPN Listener links to cert file...?

Tags: paypal, ssl-certificate, paypal-ipn

Ok, so I have this code in my ipnlistener.php file:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 
    dirname(__FILE__)."/cert/api_cert_chain.crt");
```

I downloaded this api_cert_chain.crt file here:  https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

But than I noticed this:  http://www.spicelogic.com/Products/PayPal-Certificate-Generator-for-Encrypted-Website-Payments-9

So I wonder, are we supposed to generate our own .crt file or is it safe to use the api_cert_chain.crt file from the first link to where the ipnlistener.php file is located on Github?

Just curious is all cause it seems weird to grab a .crt file with keys unknown and than use it when sending the IPN within the IPN Listener of Pay Pal.

Is this safe?  Am I supposed to generate my own crt file to use?

Answer (score 0):

The certificates mentioned in the article you linked are for Encrypted Website Payments which is unrelated to Instant Payment Notification (IPN). Well, not entirely unrelated since EWP transactions can send out an IPN post... but that isn't the point of the question.

Stick with the files provided in the IPN sample.